# Email Parsing using Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, beginner

I am new to machine learning. I have a project in which i need to extract some data from email by parsing email using machine learning and  would really appreciate if you could guide me with that. I am a bit confused where to start and how to start, kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Cupcake, welcome to the site. The approach to parsing the emails would be completely different depending on the format of the email and the type information to extract. A general solution would be to use a large language model (LLM), but simpler solutions (e.g. a regular expression) may be enough for emails with a very regular formatting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you Noe for your answer... I have a project with the help of which we are trying to extract information like origin, destination, weight details of the cargo. Right now, i am learning basics of NLP and would be really grateful if you could guide me with what i should start after NLP

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at this blog post –while their dataset is probably different from yours, their task seems the same: [Named Entity Recognition using the Enron Email Dataset in Python: Part 2](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-using-the-enron-email-dataset-in-python-part-2-fb7ce69bc473).

For a general (but comprehensive) introduction to entity extraction in Python, you may also want to take a look [at this Kaggle tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/code/eneszvo/ner-named-entity-recognition-tutorial).

Hope this helps, best of luck with the project!

Comment: Thanks JordiCarrera for the reply.. I will definitely look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you needing to extract data-elements from the emails, which are usually noun-phrases.  In that case, you may use any available NP chunkers from spacy, nltk, stanford-nlp or the likes to extract noun phrases from the email.  If you are looking to extract email ids and names, you may use NER (named-entity-recognizers) available in the open source world.

Comment: Thanks Sudar for the reply.. I will definitely look into these libraries.